# Starting a new cycle if condition is met in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am performing several commands (`GNU sed`) on a line and if certain condition is met, I want to skip rest of the commands.

Example:

1. I want to substitute all `d` with `4`
2. If line start with `A`, `C` or `E`, skip the rest of the commands (another substitutions etc)

I want to use basic regular expressions only. If I could use extended regex, this would be trivial:

```
sed -r 's/d/4/g; /^(A|C|E)/! { s/a/1/g; s/b/2/g; s/c/3/g }' data
```

Now, with *BRE*, this will work fine but for more conditions, it will be really ugly:

```
sed 's/d/4/g; /^A/! { /^C/! { /^E/! { s/a/1/g; s/b/2/g; s/c/3/g } } }' data
```

Example input:

```
Aaabbccdd
Baabbccdd
Caabbccdd
Daabbccdd
Eaabbccdd
```

Example output:

```
Aaabbcc44
B11223344
Caabbcc44
D11223344
Eaabbcc44
```

This is just an example. I am not looking for different ways to approach the problem. I want to know some better ways to *start a new cycle*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `b`:

```
/^\(A\|C\|E\)/b
```

From `man sed`:

> `b label`: Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

Comment: Ahh...let's forget I forgot it's possible to use `\( \| \)` with BRE. `b` is a brilliant suggestion. Thanks! :)

Comment: @potong yeah, but this was just an example. The conditions might me much more complicated :)

Comment: @mickp `\|` works in GNU sed only as an extension to BRE. GNU sed BRE and ERE only differ in what needs to be escaped.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh, I see. So in non-GNU `sed`, I would have to do: `/^A/b; /^B/b ...`?

Comment: @mickp To get alternation, you'd need ERE, which [POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) currently doesn't require, but probably [will soon](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528). The suggestion is to use `-E` for ERE; GNU sed supports `-r` and (inofficially, until recently) `-E`.